# Should't the height of the frame match the height constraint of an imageview?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, constraints, frame

Basically, I have a function that sets up my image view. It is inside of a cell in a collectionview. 
It's a square imageview that I am placing halfway up another view.

The issue is that for some reason, the constraint that I put on the height, does not seem to match the .frame.height.

I made an outlet to my height constraint property. I set it as the height of the cell * 0.10.

When I print the imageviewHeight.constant/2 , I get 23.345. When I print the self.imageview.frame.height/2, I get 25.

Should't the height of the frame match the height constraint?

```
private func setupImageView() {
    imageviewHeight.constant = self.frame.height * 0.10
    imageviewWidth.constant = imageviewHeight.constant
    imageviewtopconstraint.constant = -(imageviewHeight.constant * 0.50)
    imageviewleftconstraint.constant = imageviewWidth.constant - (imageviewHeight.constant * 0.50)
    self.updateConstraints()

// imageview is the outlet to the UIImageView

    print(imageviewHeight.constant/2)
    print(self.imageview.frame.height/2)

   self.imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageviewHeight.constant / 2
   self.imageview.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: When are you calling `setupImageView`. If it's called before the cell is given a chance to do layout, that could cause this.

Comment: What is the imageview's content mode?

Comment: I call the function after I set up the rest of the cell, which is basically just the header view. The imageview's content mode is aspect fit. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private func setupImageView() {
  imageviewHeight.constant = self.frame.height * 0.10
  imageviewWidth.constant = imageviewHeight.constant
  imageviewtopconstraint.constant = -(imageviewHeight.constant * 0.50)
  imageviewleftconstraint.constant = imageviewWidth.constant - (imageviewHeight.constant * 0.50)
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

  // imageview is the outlet to the UIImageView

  print(imageviewHeight.constant/2)
  print(self.imageview.frame.height/2)

  self.imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageviewHeight.constant / 2
  self.imageview.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: Hey, I changed it to that and now the imageviewHeight.constant/2 is giving me 23.345 like before, but the other one is now giving me 23.25. Very close yet still not exact. Not sure why

Comment: Try print the values after you called clipsToBounds and see what happens

Comment: The same thing happens

Comment: Are you sure that you don't use any other constraints that overrides these settings?